# I want to add a new font

Tags: joomla-3.x, helix3, fonts

I want to add a new font to helix3 template, the font I want to use isn't in the google font list that the template provides,how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your templates CSS file (mostly custom.css) import the google font you want to use like

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

More information can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676613/how-to-import-google-web-font-in-css-file.